# How correctly to insert an SQL query inside For statement in a Macro?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I want to pass the iterations of FOR statements inside a query in a Excel Macro:

```
For i=1 To 9 
    For j=1 To 3 

    Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE  ref1='i' AND ref2='j'")
    ...
    Next j
Next i
```

I get this error:
"Error converting data type varchar to bigint"

On the database the values of ref1 and ref2 are float.

How can I insert the parameters correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to concat values of `i` and `j`.

```
For i=1 To 9 
    For j=1 To 3 

    Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE  ref1='" & i & "' AND ref2='" & j & "'")
    ...
    Next j
Next i
```